# Trouble with Selenium Python related Imports

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I'm going to make an application using the Selenium WebDriver (python) and I was having trouble with some of the initial setup. I want to use the page object design pattern so I've been trying to import some materials in this way:

```
from page_objects import PageObject, PageElementfrom page_objects import PageObject, PageElement
```

as can bee seen in the documentation here: https://page-objects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#a-simple-page-object

I'm using PyCharm for development and I've updated selenium and added it to the project interpreter but this import statement still will not work for me. I'm not sure which external module this import relates to or if its just some part of selenium, so any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That readthedocs is for the `page_objects` library, the repo for that library [can be found here](https://github.com/eeaston/page-objects). You need to install that library before you can import it